# How pass only some params to stored proc in Coldfusion10?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

At CF Summit 2016 it was recommended not to call stored procs using cfquery tag, but rather to use cfstoredproc instead. I have a proc that a previous programmer called using cfquery, and I want to rewrite it to use cfstoredproc. However, the proc has many params, and I only want to pass 3, and have the rest go to their default values. We're running CF10, however, so dbvarname isn't an attribute of cfprocparam and isn't added back until CF11.

Is there any reason, with respect to security or speed of execution, that I shouldn't just call the proc this way?:

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="myResult">
    EXEC p_myProc
        @type_id=3
        ,@action_id=0
        ,@id=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#id#" />
</cfquery>
```

I could instead use cfprocparam this way, making sure that the params I'm passing are the first three defined in the proc and in correct order:

```
<cfstoredproc datasource="#application.dsn#" result="myResult" procedure="p_myProc">
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="3" />
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="0" />
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#id#" />
</cfstoredproc>
```

But what if those 3 params were defined in the middle, or not in direct sequence? I'd rather not have to pass a value for every single param, because that's a lot of typing, and I'd have to look up their default values in the proc, and those default values could always change and then the CF code would be overriding them.

Comment: I doubt there's any performance difference between `cfstoredproc` and `cfquery with EXEC`. Security won't be a concern with `cfqueryparam` either.

Comment: The only time using `cfstoredproc` is critical is when the SP returns more than one set of results.  The code you want to replace is not broken.  Don't try to fix it.

Comment: What reasons did they give for the recommendation? My guess is the primary reasons are what was already mentioned above 1) Security. CFStored proc *forces* parameterization, whereas cfquery does not 2) CFQuery does not support all of the same capabilities. While personally I prefer cfstoredproc, since you are using cfqueryparam it does not sound mandatory in this specific case. Having said that, typing parameters is a one time event (and can be auto generated from db metadata for the lazy like me). So the point about default values is a more compelling argument against switching IMO.

Comment: ... though I tend to group all parameters with default values at the end of the declaration, so they can easily be omitted if necessary.

Comment: Security was the issue - I believe the recommendation was made by David Epler in his security talk. He suggested never running `EXEC` inside a `<cfquery>` tag.